# why does recognizer.location(in:) return larger x and y values than the bounds of the view?

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I want to implement a simple program to show the color of the point your finger is located on an image using a UIPanGestureRecognizer. But the x and y values of the CGPoint returned from gesture.location(in:) function are greater than expected, thus the selected color from the image is not correct.

For instance, the imageView.frame.size.width prints as 375. But when you drag to the right of the screen, the largest returned value of the x position of the pan gesture is 413.

Why are the x and y values of the returned CGPoint greater than the bounds of the UIImageView?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
var squareView: UIView!
var imgheight: CGFloat!
var imgwidth: CGFloat!
var heightDif: CGFloat!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    squareView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
    squareView.backgroundColor = getPixelColor(pos: CGPoint(x: 50, y: 50))
    view.addSubview(squareView)

    imgheight = imageView.image?.size.height
    imgwidth = imageView.image?.size.width
    heightDif = (imageView.frame.size.height - imgheight)/2

    let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePan(recognizer:)))
    imageView.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func getPixelColor(pos: CGPoint) -> UIColor {

    let pixelData = imageView.image?.cgImage!.dataProvider!.data
    let data: UnsafePointer<UInt8> = CFDataGetBytePtr(pixelData)

    let pixelInfo: Int = ((Int(imageView.image!.size.width) * Int(pos.y)) + Int(pos.x)) * 4

    let r = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo]) / CGFloat(255.0)
    let g = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+1]) / CGFloat(255.0)
    let b = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+2]) / CGFloat(255.0)
    let a = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+3]) / CGFloat(255.0)

    return UIColor(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: a)
}

@objc func handlePan(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    var point = recognizer.location(in: self.imageView)
    point.y -= heightDif
    if point.x >= 0 && point.y >= 0 {
        squareView.backgroundColor = getPixelColor(pos: point)
    }

}
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by creating the imageView programmatically instead of using the storyboard. This gave me exact control over the imageView's parameters, and the recognizer.location function returned the expected results.

```
var imageView: UIImageView!
```

Then, I declared its bounds in viewDidLoad():

```
frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: image.size.wdith, height: image.size.height)
imageView = UIImageView(frame: frame)
view.addSubview(imageView)
```

And the rest of the code is the same, and everything works!